# How to stop NSOperationQueue during dispatch_async

Tags: objective-c

I'm adding many block-operations to an operationsqueue in a for loop. In each operation I need to check on another thread if a condition is fulfilled. If the condition is fulfilled, all operations should be cancelled.

I made a sample code to show you my problem:

```
__block BOOL queueDidCancel = NO;
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10", nil];

NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
myQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount =1;


for (NSString *string in array) {
    [myQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        if (queueDidCancel) {return;}
        NSLog(@"run: %@", string);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                queueDidCancel = YES;
                [myQueue cancelAllOperations];
            }
        });
    }];
}
```

Expected output from NSLog:

```
run: 1
```

Output I got (it varies between 7 and 9):

```
run: 1
run: 2
run: 3
run: 4
run: 5
run: 6
run: 7
run: 8
```

I googled for hours, but I could not find a solution.

Comment: You need to sync access to ```queueDidCancel``` but that is not the problem. The queue is cancelled but it is too late as by then all the blocks finished running. Just add an NSLog where you cancel the queue that log something like "Cancelled" and you will see what I mean. But the biggest problem is that even if you do it all correctly it will not necessarily cancel running tasks. For that you need a bit more logic.

Comment: @skaak You are right. The queue is cancelled, but too late. Btw. I don't need to stop the current running operation. I only want to prevent the OperationQueue to start executing the next operations.

Comment: That's `[myQueue setSuspended: true]`. Preventing a queue from scheduling is called suspending not cancelling. Queues cannot be cancelled.

Comment: @RobNapier I think here we need both - stop running ones and also prevent scheduling new ones. This is what I did in my example and using a simple albeit synced boolean. That one boolean prevents new blocks from being scheduled and also causes running ones to stop executing.

Comment: Chris, can you edit your question and give us an idea of what these ten operations are doing? The correct solution depends upon these operations are doing...

Comment: Since the operation runs in the back you can test your condition inside a ```sync``` not ```async``` block and I *think* here it actually makes a lot of sense. You add lots of blocks in your sample and I don't think that is good but again it depends. What I want to suggest is that you check inside your block inside a ```sync``` and if the condition is met add the *next* block *inside* the running block. Again, this is a suggestion based on current understanding ...

Comment: @skaak thanks, I'll definitely give it a try

Comment: I've edited my answer to give an example of what I mean. I also give a simplified one where you do it all inside a single block's while loop. That might be the one for you and you can replace the xxx with whatever logic you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. Here's the updated code:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10", nil];

NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
myQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount =1;


for (NSString *string in array) {
    [myQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [myQueue setSuspended:YES];
        NSLog(@"run: %@", string);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (![string isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                [myQueue setSuspended:NO];
            }
        });
    }];
}
```

Comment: Ok but this is a toy example. The first block just suspends the queue. The rest are still added but because of the suspension not executed. Then on the main thread later you continue running it. It does not make sense for what you want unless you want a continue button not a cancel one? You want (lots of) stuff to be running in the back and then to cancel them later on main. I think my answer works here as it does both - it prevents the running of any blocks that may be running at present and it prevents adding any new blocks. This is what you want to do right?

Comment: Another comment - my example uses a lock to sync the boolean but in a class you could use an atomic ivar as well. Then you can just get and set it as you please as the OS will sync the access to it.

Comment: Chris, it's not clear to me what problem this is solving. What if the `@"1"` wasn't the first string in the array. This code would just stop. Is that what you were attempting to accomplish?

Comment: @skaak yeah, every operation suspends the queue at the beginning of execution. As I found in the docs, the current operation will be finished (that's what I want), even when the queue is suspended. And when the dispatch_async block is finished it can decide to resume the queue or not. You are right, that's like a continue button and not a cancel button. But it's not about a button to stop. It's about doing something on another thread (not UI) and based on the result, stop execution. I should have been clearer in my problem description.

Comment: Ok that is mostly how I got it ... it is a bit different in that you *want* the running operation to run to completion. I thought you want to *cancel* any running ones when the event (eg click) happens. Then you can actually use suspend or cancel. Another question - will you ever have more than one operation running in the back at any point in time?

Comment: I'm using an external library which can't be used on more than 1 operation at the same time, so no. `maxConcurrentOperationCount` will always be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Let me use more space. You need to sync access to your variable. It is the correct idea but you are using it incorrectly. You need a lock or an atomic ivar or something like that to sync access to it.

Then if you cancel in the dispatch_async bit it happens looooong after all the blocks executed. That is what your output shows. As mentioned in the comment, if you add a NSLog e.g.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                queueDidCancel = YES;
                // Add here
                NSLog(@"Going to cancel now");
                [myQueue cancelAllOperations];
            }
```

you will see what I mean. I expect that to typically execute deep into your array or even after all of the array finished executing.

But the biggest problem is your logic. You need some logic to cancel those blocks. Just messaging `cancelAllOperations` or `setSuspended` is not enough and blocks that are already running will keep on running.

Here is a quick example.

```
NSObject * lock = NSObject.new;      // Use this to sync access
__block BOOL queueDidCancel = NO;

NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
myQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount =1;

for (NSString *string in array) {
    // Here you also need to add some logic, e.g. as below
    // Note the sync access
    @synchronized ( lock ) {
      if (queueDidCancel) { break; }
    }

    [myQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

        // You need to sync access to queueDidCancel especially if
        // you access it from main and the queue or if you increase
        // the concurrent count
        // This lock is one way of doing it, there are others
        @synchronized ( lock ) {
          // Here is your cancel logic! This is fine here
          if (queueDidCancel) {return;}
        }

        NSLog(@"run: %@", string);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if ([string isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                // Again you need to sync this
                @synchronized ( lock ) {
                  queueDidCancel = YES;
                }
                // This is not needed your logic should take care of it ...
                // The problem is that running threads will probably
                // keep on running and you need logic to stop them
                // [myQueue cancelAllOperations];
            }
        });
    }];
}
```

Now this example does what yours does but with a bit more locking and a bit more logic and NO cancelAllOperations nor suspended = YESs. This will not do what you want as even with this running threads tend to run to completion and you need logic to stop it.

Also, in this example, I left the exit or cancel condition as is in the main thread. Again here this will probably mean nothing gets cancelled, but in real life you'd typically cancel from some UI e.g. a button click and then you'd do it as here. But you could cancel anywhere using the lock.

**EDIT**

Based on lots of comments here is another possible way.

Here you check inside the block and based on the check add another block or not.

```
    NSOperationQueue * queue = NSOperationQueue.new;

    // Important
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

    void ( ^ block ) ( void ) = ^ {

        // Whatever you have to do ... do it here
        xxx

        // Perform check
        // Note I run it sync and on the main queue, your requirements may differ
        dispatch_sync ( dispatch_get_main_queue (), ^ {

            // Here the condition is stop or not
            // YES means continue adding blocks
            if ( cond )
            {
                [queue addOperationWithBlock:block];
            }
            // else done

        } );

    };

    // Start it all
    [queue addOperationWithBlock:block];
```

Above I use the *same* block every time which is also quite an assumption but you can change it easily to add different blocks. However, if the blocks are all the same you will only need one and do not need to keep on scheduling new blocks and then can do it as below.

```
    void ( ^ block1 ) ( void ) = ^ {

        // Some logic
        __block BOOL done = NO;

        while ( ! done )
        {
            // Whatever you have to do ... do it here
            xxx

            // Perform check
            // Note I run it sync and on the main queue, your requirements may differ
            dispatch_sync ( dispatch_get_main_queue (), ^ {

                // Here the condition is stop or not
                // YES means stop! here
                done = cond;

            } );
        }

    };
```

Comment: This reproduces all of this `queueDidCancel` logic from the original post, which should be excised.

Comment: It keeps the logic, adds to it and syncs it and also shows how to use it in typical UI environment. If you remove it then the moment you change from serial to concurrent queue you rewrite it all again. This works for serial and concurrent queue, for UI or background cancel etc.

Comment: Cancelation is quite simple (and the serial vs concurrent is irrelevant). When you cancel an operation before it starts, it just won't run. If you want to cancel operations that may have already started, then you to periodically check `isCancelled` while the long running operation is running (or if async operation subclass, sometimes override `cancel` implementation). But the OP's addition of yet another boolean on top of the existing boolean that is already provided is poor design.

Comment: @skaak thanks for clarification, but is there no way to prevent executing the next operation until the dispatch_async has finished?

Comment: You could use ```dispatch_sync``` - but there are many ways. Not entirely sure what you want to do?

Comment: @Rob We are talking about running operations here. In stead of using a simple boolean you are suggesting subclassing NSOperation. Is that good design? Also, is it good design to use NSOperationQueue's cancelAllOperations here. When you cancel, you need to store the cancelled state somewhere - hey, how about in a boolean. You are suggesting dropping the boolean ... ok, then how will you know that you are in cancelled state? Will you use one of the operations' cancelled state for that? Which one?

Comment: Is subclassing `NSOperation` a good idea. Generally, yes, in the spirit of the single responsibility principle. But even if you don't, you create a `NSBlockOperation`, add an execution block to it in which you check the `isCancelled`. But adding another layer of booleans on top of the ones that are already there are rarely a good idea.

Comment: What I mean is how will you check the cancelled state to stop adding new blocks to the queue without that boolean? (Yes *inside* the block you could use its own cancelled state). You subclass NSOperation to store that state?

Comment: His question wasn't how to stop adding new operations, but rather how to cancel previously added ones (and he simply seemed to be confused about the timing of when all these operations started and ended and the timing of the cancelation from another thread). Bottom line, if he wants boolean to know if operation has been canceled, that exists. If you want to check to see if queue is suspended, there's a property for that. Anything that reproduces that logic is questionable, IMHO.

Comment: @Rob what a rollercoaster ... yes I think you are overkilling here with a subclass and it became a fierce debate but that is also just IMHO and thanks I appreciate it actually. We ended up debating and answering OP all at the same time ... thanks.